# How to pass return statement variable to another function variable?

Tags: java, android

In class order, it return new BigInteger. I have wanted to pass the new BigInteger to pass_order() function variables trx_id. How should i pass it?

```
public class order {
public final class SessionIdentifierGenerator {
    private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    public String nextSessionId() {
        return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
    }
}
private void pass_order() {
    String trx_id = SessionIdentifierGenerator(BigInteger;
}
```

Comment: Make the nextSessionId() function static, then call SessionIdentifierGenerator.nextSessionId() from function pass_order.

Comment: @mdewit : You cant mak nextSessionId() static buddy :) Inner class can not have static declaration :) I thought the same early then I realised it wont work that way :)

Comment: Yeah to do that the SessionIdentifierGenerator class will have to be a static as well. Which it should be, as it is a separate functioning unit. Eg public static final class SessionIdentifierGenerator { public static String nextSessionId() {...}};

Comment: @mdewit : I agree :)

Comment: @CheongCharlene Do you know you can accept the solution which solves your problem? So far, you have accepted none of the answers to all your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :)

```
public class order {
        public final class SessionIdentifierGenerator {
            private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

            public String nextSessionId() {
                return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
            }
        }
        private void pass_order() {
            SessionIdentifierGenerator sessionIDGenerator = new SessionIdentifierGenerator();
            String trx_id = sessionIDGenerator.nextSessionId();
        }
    }
```